# How to set change placeholder color on searchbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

```
extension UISearchBar {

private func getViewElement<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {

    let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
    guard let element = (svs.filter { $0 is T }).first as? T else { return nil }
    return element
}

func getSearchBarTextField() -> UITextField? {

    return getViewElement(type: UITextField.self)
}

func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {

    if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {
        textField.textColor = color
    }
}

func setTextFieldColor(color: UIColor) {

    if let textField = getViewElement(type: UITextField.self) {
        switch searchBarStyle {
        case .minimal:
            textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        case .prominent, .default:
            textField.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}

func setPlaceholderTextColor(color: UIColor) {

    if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:color])
    }
}

func setPlaceholderfont(fontfamily: UIFont) {

    if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:fontfamily])
    }
}


 }
```

I have created an extension for Uisearchbbar so that i can able to customize the placeholder

In extension **setPlaceholderfont()**  is working fine

when I call the below method the color of the placeholder text is not changing

```
pick.searchBar.setPlaceholderTextColor(color: Server().primarycolor)
```

Comment: If you call `setPlaceholderTextColor` without also calling `setPlaceholderfont`, does the color change? Those two methods don't keep any existing placeholder attributes.

Comment: no effect still same! @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the two methods to update the attributed placeholders' color and font, you're overwriting one with the last. So assuming you're setting the color first and the font second, the color attribute is removed when setting the font attribute.

A simple way to avoid this is start with a single point of entry that updates the placeholder attributes, which is used by both the color and font setter methods. I have used a computed property that has both a getter and setter – it can get and set the current attributes of the placeholder.

```
extension UITextField {
    var placeholderColor: UIColor? {
        get { return placeholderAttributes?[.foregroundColor] as? UIColor }
        set { placeholderAttributes?[.foregroundColor] = newValue }
    }

    var placeholderFont: UIFont? {
        get { return placeholderAttributes?[.font] as? UIFont }
        set { placeholderAttributes?[.font] = newValue }
    }

    var placeholderAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? {
        get { return attributedPlaceholder?.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) }
        set { attributedPlaceholder = .init(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: newValue) }
    }
}
```

So cut back to your `UISearchBar` extension (I would replace the `getSearchBarTextField` method with a computed property `textField`), we can remove any reference to attributed strings etc.

```
var textField: UITextField? {
    return getViewElement(type: UITextField.self)
}

func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {
    textField?.textColor = color
}

func setPlaceholderTextColor(color: UIColor) {
    textField?.placeholderColor = color
}

func setPlaceholderFont(font: UIFont) {
    textField?.placeholderFont = font
}
```

---

Although properties with the appropriate types (`UIColor`, `UIFont`) may come in handy in some situations, you technically don't need the `placeholderColor` and `placeholderFont` properties, as you can just set them using the text field `placeholderAttributes` property from the extension.

```
extension UITextField {
    var placeholderAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? {
        get { return attributedPlaceholder?.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) }
        set { attributedPlaceholder = .init(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: newValue) }
    }
}

extension UISearchBar {

    // ...

    func setPlaceholderTextColor(color: UIColor) {
        textField?.placeholderAttributes?[.foregroundColor] = color
    }

    func setPlaceholderfont(fontfamily: UIFont) {
        textField?.placeholderAttributes?[.font] = fontfamily
    }
}
```